# Coda Terminal can't find rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, coda

I've installed rails using rvm and everything works well in the out of the box terminal using zsh. I thought i'd simplify things a bit and bring out Coda's terminal but for some reason when I run 
`$ rails --version` 
I get errors saying there are missing dependencies or when using `$ rails new new_app` Coda terminal tells me that rails isn't installed. running `$ gem list` and `$ gem environment` give me the same output in both terminals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to load rvm before using it
load rvm script with

```
 source ~/.rvm/bin/rvm
```